# Magento 1: Stop supporting Flash at the end of 2020

Tags: magento-1.9

Reference url: https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/saying-goodbye-flash-chrome/

Adobe announced its plans to stop supporting Flash at the end of 2020. And google announced that remove **Flash** completely from Chrome toward the end of 2020.

Still we are using magento1 and image upload depended on flash. if flash removed from chrome, how to upload images in magento 1?

1. is all magento 1 version depended on flash? (currently using 1.9.4.4)
2. is there any patch from magento for this issue?
3. what are the impact on magento 1, if flash removed from browser?
4. what is the solution for the image upload, if flash removed from browser?

Comment: this can be helpful for youhttps://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1 is has passed the EOL mark so **no new updates will be provided by Magento** itself. You might look into [OpenMage](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts) which is an opensource project to continue the support of Magento 1.

If I'm not mistaken, the issue you mentioned (Flash upload) is fixed in there.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the uploader? Is it within an extension or core?

I could be mistaken but I'm almost certain this was resolved in SUPEE 8788 and 1.9.3 release

Core team switched to JS uploader for reason you outlined

https://support.hypernode.com/en/best-practices/security/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-8788-and-release-1-9-3

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788

```
APPSEC-666 - Cross-site scripting in Flash file uploader
```

If it's within an extension it's best you raise with the dev

Comment: Does this change will make image uploader works on Magento 1.9.2.1 ?